# How many solutions for an equation: $3\ln x + mx^3 = 17\;$?

Tags: calculus

> Let $3\ln x + mx^3 = 17$. Then there's one solution? two? none?

What I did is defining $f(x) = 3ln(x) + mx^3 - 17$. We want to know when $f(x)=0$. Then, we can use Rolle's Thm for that cause. Lets take the derivative:
$f'(x) = {3 \over x} + 3mx^2$ 
comparing $f'(x) = 0$ we get:
${1 \over x} = -mx^2$.

What should I do at this point?

Comment: The equation $1/x=-mx^2$ is morally equivalent to $1=-mx^3$ (since $x>0$ by the domain of the original). How many solutions does that have? What does that tell you about the original?

Comment: So, there's no solution, because $x^3 > 0$ by the domain of the original function. Therefore, it cannot be equal a negative value.

Comment: No one said (here, anyway) that $m$ couldn't be negative....  (And then you still have to go back to the original as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$f(x)=3\ln x +mx^3-17$$

Note that

$$f'(x)={3\over x}+3mx^2$$

and

$$f''(x)=-{3\over x^2}+6mx$$

Note also that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=-\infty$.

There are two cases to be considered:  $m\ge0$ and $m\lt0$.

If $m\ge0$, then $f'(x)\gt0$ for all $x\gt0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing.  Also, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, so $f(x)=0$ has exactly one solution.

If $m\lt0$, then $f''(x)\lt0$ for all $x\gt0$, so $f$ is concave down. Also, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, so $f(x)=0$ has either no solutions, one solution, or two solutions, depending on whether the maximum value of $f$ is less than $0$, equal to $0$, or greater than $0$.  The maximum value occurs when $f'(x)=0$, i.e., when $x^3=-1/m$.  It is equal to $\ln(x^3)+mx^3-17=\ln(-1/m)-1-17=-\ln(-m)-18$.  Hence there is *no* solution if $m\lt-e^{-18}$, *one* solution if $m=-e^{-18}$, and *two* solutions if $-e^{-18}\lt m\lt0$.

Remark:  In terms of the number of solutions, we would have done just as well to consider the function

$$g(x)=\ln x +mx-17$$

since $f(x)=g(x^3)$.  The results are precisely the same, except that the maximum of $g$ (when $m\lt0$) occurs at $x=-1/m$.  In other words, there's really no cubic polynomial playing any role here.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides of your equation by $x$ (which we can do, since $x\gt 0$).

Now, [how many solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) can there be to the equation $\,1=-mx^3\;$?

So how many solutions to $\;3\ln x + mx^3 = 17\;?$

Comment: No solution at all. Right?

Comment: Try again! Why do you think there's no solution? Note that if $m <0$, then  $\;x^3 = -\frac 1{m} > 0$.

Comment: because $x^3 = {1 \over {-m}}$ and $x^3$ is positive

Comment: You're forgetting that $m$ can be negative! When $m<0$, $x^3>0$.

Comment: Can you help me complete it please?

Comment: A cubic equation has either $1$ or $3$ solutions (see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation)). Since $x^3 > 0$, it's root(s) must necessarily be greater than zero (given the domain of the function), and hence there can be only one solution. Therefore, there is exactly one solution to the the equation, and hence exactly one solution to the original equation.